# Checking the number of items before adding new ones to Firebase through AngularFireDatabase

Tags: ionic-framework, observable, angularfire2

I am writing a function to add a record (quote) to Firebase but I want to limit the number of records to 3. The function is shown below:

```
addQuote(q) {

   this.angularFireDatabase.list(this.getUserPath('/savedQuoteList')).valueChanges().subscribe( data => {
     console.log("Length = "+data.length);

     if(data.length<3){
       this.angularFireDatabase.list(this.getUserPath('/savedQuoteList')).push(q);
       console.log("Quote saved.");
     } else {
       console.log("Too many quotes in list.");
     }
  });

}
```

When the list length is 3, the function indicates that there are too many quotes in list, which is the expected behavior. However, if I now remove some records manually on Firebase, then the function adds back the records that I previously failed to add until the list length is 3 (or even 4 in some cases).

I know that this must be because I have subscribed to the list, and therefore it is being listened to. I have tried adding `.unsubscribe()` to the end but then the records are not added at all. How can I get it to work? Alternatively, is there a simpler way to do it?

I know this should be straightforward but I'm not yet familiar with observables so I need some help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with firebase native methods to check the list

First `import * as firebase from 'firebase';`

```
firebase.database().ref(this.getUserPath('/savedQuoteList')).once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.numChildren());
    if(snapshot.numChildren()<3){
       this.angularFireDatabase.list(this.getUserPath('/savedQuoteList')).push(q);
       console.log("Quote saved.");
    }else {
       console.log("Too many quotes in list.");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working now. One minor issue: When I use the code your suggested, the `this` in `this.angularFireDatabase.list(...)` becomes undefined. I solved it by defining the reference `afdRef = this.angularFireDatabase.list(...)` beforehand and then using the reference inside. So my further question is, how can I correctly refer to `this` inside the `.then{}` code?

Comment: Problem solved. I now realize that it is a scoping issue. I changed the `function(snapshot){...}` to `snapshot=>{...}` and now it's working.